# Take a row from n dataframes and create a new dataframe with the rows taken, R

Tags: r, dataframe

Assume I have 2 dataframes. I want to select only a row, let's say industry c3, from every dataframe and put them in another data.frame, df3.

```
df1 = data.frame(Industries = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"), Exports = c(100, 40, 30, 10, 50), Imports =c(90,50,25,15,50))
df2 = data.frame(Industries = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"), Exports = c(20, 90, 10, 30, 60), Imports =c(40,30,25,55,40))

df1
      Industries Exports Imports
    1         c1     100      90
    2         c2      40      50
    3         c3      30      25
    4         c4      10      15
    5         c5      50      50
df2
      Industries Exports Imports
    1         c1      20      40
    2         c2      90      30
    3         c3      10      25
    4         c4      30      55
    5         c5      60      40
```

In my real data I have 16 different dataframes, so if possible the code should allow to put 16 rows from 16 dataframes in another one, that will be created.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(list(df1, df2), subset, Industries == "c3"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your columns are always identical, you can do the following with dplyr and purrr packages:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df1 = data.frame(Industries = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"), Exports = c(100, 40, 30, 10, 50), Imports =c(90,50,25,15,50))
df2 = data.frame(Industries = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"), Exports = c(20, 90, 10, 30, 60), Imports =c(40,30,25,55,40))

list(df1, df2) %>% map_df(~ filter(., Industries == "c3"))
#>   Industries Exports Imports
#> 1         c3      30      25
#> 2         c3      10      25
```

- `list(df1, df2)` is combining your data frames into a list
- `map_df` iterates on each, promising (if possible) to return results as a data frame.
- `~ filter(., Industries == "c3")` is the function run on each data frame, which returns only the rows where `Industries == "c3"`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Place the datasets in a `list` with `mget` and `paste`, `rbind` the datasets in the `list` (`rbindlist`), set the 'key' as 'Industries' and subset the rows that have 'c3' in the column

```
library(data.table)
setkey(rbindlist(mget(paste0("df", 1:2))), "Industries")["c3"]
#   Industries Exports Imports
#1:         c3      30      25
#2:         c3      10      25
```